# Customized update route for each field of a form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to save each field of a form individually. But I have really hard time implementing it.

Here's the code I am trying.

users_controller.rb:

```
def update_name
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:name))
    # Handle a successful update.
    flash[:success] = "Name updated"
    redirect_to edit_user_path
  else
    render 'edit'   
  end
end

def update_email
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:email))
    # Handle a successful update.
    flash[:success] = "Email updated"
    render 'edit'
  else
    render 'edit'   
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'users/:id/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
get  '/users/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
patch 'users/:id/name'=> 'users#update_name'
patch 'users/:id/email'=> 'users#update_email'
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<%= f.button "Save", :action => "update_name" , :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-primary", id:"editAccount" %>

<%= f.button "Save", :action => "update_email" , :method => :patch, class: "btn btn-primary", id:"editAccount" %>
```

I can go with normal update but I would like to save the fields individually. How can I change the route from normal update route(users/:id).

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: what is the problem in this? why you have to same id "id:"editAccount"  ??

Comment: If you will use normal update and you will update one field it will update only that field. I did not get what is the problem ?

Comment: I can save the fields even using a single def successfully. But I need a user to enter a password to update an email address, which is not required for updating a simple name. For this reason, I am trying to add two definitions but I am not able to route them correctly. With the above code I got a routing error "No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1"

Comment: where is your form? could you paste here?

Comment: I have added the answer check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with your update method , also I have not added how you are updaing passowd so please check on that.

```
def update
  if params[:user][:email].blank? and params[:user][:password].blank?  
    @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:name))
    flash[:success] = "Name updated"
    redirect_to edit_user_path
  elsif params[:user][:email].present? and params[:user][:password].present?
    @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:email))
    flash[:success] = "Email updated"
    render 'edit'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end 
end
```

Comment: Great!!! That does help. I need to update the method to match the functionality that I am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SumaChaganti It is good practice to accept answer if it is working for you thanks

Comment: I did. Thanks again :)